# MATLAB GUI - how to make a button change a value then close window

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

I am doing data processing from experiments, some data cannot be detected and given a 'type'. For this data I have made a GUI that plots the relevant data and allows the user to manually specify what data 'type' it is by means of 5 buttons.

The idea is this: if the data cannot be assigned a 'type' by the script a window opens asking for user input. Once the user presses the button indicating the 'type' a number is assigned/saved into the parent script and the window is closed.

Everything is working except saving the 'type' (integer as identifier) such that the parent script can read this. See below for a simplified version of what I have done so far:

```
xCur = 1:1000;
yCur = 1:1000;
i = 1;

[fig,currentExpType] = guiExpType(xCur,yCur);
waitfor(fig);
disp(['Experiment series ' num2str(i) ' is type ' num2str(currentExpType) ' (user input)']);


function [fig,expType] = guiExpType(xCur, yCur)

expType = [];

% prompt window
fig = uifigure;
fig.Name = "Determine Experiment Type";
fig.Position = [350 300 1200 675];

% determine prompt layout
gl = uigridlayout(fig,[9 2]);
gl.RowHeight = {40,30,40,40,40,40,40};
gl.ColumnWidth = {'1x',200};

% initiate modules in prompt
ttl = uilabel(gl,'Text','Unable to detect experiment type, please define with the buttons below.','FontSize',20,'FontWeight','bold');
lbl = uilabel(gl,'Text','Experiment type shown:');
axX = uiaxes(gl);
axY = uiaxes(gl);
btn1 = uibutton(gl,'Text','Positive x perturbation','ButtonPushedFcn',@(src,event)btn_callback(src,event,1));
btn2 = uibutton(gl,'Text','Negative y perturbation','ButtonPushedFcn',@(src,event)btn_callback(src,event,2));
btn3 = uibutton(gl,'Text','Negative x perturbation','ButtonPushedFcn',@(src,event)btn_callback(src,event,3));
btn4 = uibutton(gl,'Text','Positive y perturbation','ButtonPushedFcn',@(src,event)btn_callback(src,event,4));
btn5 = uibutton(gl,'Text','Undefined, skip this.','ButtonPushedFcn',@(src,event)btn_callback(src,event,5));

% layout of modules
% title
ttl.Layout.Row = 1;
ttl.Layout.Column = [1 2];
% label
lbl.Layout.Row = 2;
lbl.Layout.Column = 2;
% button expType1
btn1.Layout.Row = 3;
btn1.Layout.Column = 2;
% button expType2
btn2.Layout.Row = 4;
btn2.Layout.Column = 2;
% button expType3
btn3.Layout.Row = 5;
btn3.Layout.Column = 2;
% button expType4
btn4.Layout.Row = 6;
btn4.Layout.Column = 2;
% button undefined
btn5.Layout.Row = 7;
btn5.Layout.Column = 2;
% x plot
axX.Layout.Row = [2 4];
axX.Layout.Column = 1;
% y plot
axY.Layout.Row = [5 7];
axY.Layout.Column = 1;

% configure modules
axX.Title.String = 'Current Experiment Cursor x-data';
axY.Title.String = 'Current Experiment Cursor y-data';

% plot data on axes
plot(axX, xCur)
plot(axY, yCur)

% callback functions for buttons

    function btn_callback(src,event,newValue)
        expType = newValue;
        closereq();
    end
    
end
```

I have tried a whole bunch of different things but am losing inspiration, I don't think I fully understand the way the the nested function definition *@(...,...)function(...,...)* works. I do understand that in the callback I am defining a variable and then immediately closing the figure, I have tried using the *set()* and *get()* functions but haven't been successful.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Context:
The GUI I need simply allows the user to manually determine the experiment type when the preceding code is unable to identify (step response in positive or negative x or y direction). After that the rest of the script will perform some necessary data filtering and system identification on the signals depending on the the experiment type.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Dear BOT, my code is already heavily trimmed. I can trim even more but then I think some of the context will be gone.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/guihandles.html) should give you an idea of how to implement it.

```
function  guiExpType

xCur = 1:1000;
yCur = 1:1000;

% prompt window
fig = uifigure;
fig.Name = "Determine Experiment Type";
fig.Position = [350 300 1200 675];

myhandles = guihandles(fig);
myhandles.expType = [];
myhandles.newType = [];

% determine prompt layout
gl = uigridlayout(fig,[9 2]);
gl.RowHeight = {40,30,40,40,40,40,40};
gl.ColumnWidth = {'1x',200};

% initiate modules in prompt
ttl = uilabel(gl,'Text','Unable to detect experiment type, please define with the buttons below.','FontSize',20,'FontWeight','bold');
lbl = uilabel(gl,'Text','Experiment type shown:');
axX = uiaxes(gl);
axY = uiaxes(gl);
btn1 = uibutton(gl,'Text','Positive x perturbation','ButtonPushedFcn',@(src,event)btn_callback(src,event,1));
btn2 = uibutton(gl,'Text','Negative y 2 perturbation','ButtonPushedFcn',@(src,event)btn_callback_2(src,event,312));
btn3 = uibutton(gl,'Text','Negative x 2 perturbation','ButtonPushedFcn',@(src,event)btn_callback_3(src,event,3));
btn4 = uibutton(gl,'Text','Positive y perturbation','ButtonPushedFcn',@(src,event)btn_callback(src,event,4));
btn5 = uibutton(gl,'Text','Undefined, skip this.','ButtonPushedFcn',@(src,event)btn_callback(src,event,5));

% dataType = myhandles.expType;
% dataType = myhandles.newType;

% layout of modules
% title
ttl.Layout.Row = 1;
ttl.Layout.Column = [1 2];
% label
lbl.Layout.Row = 2;
lbl.Layout.Column = 2;
% button expType1
btn1.Layout.Row = 3;
btn1.Layout.Column = 2;
% button expType2
btn2.Layout.Row = 4;
btn2.Layout.Column = 2;
% button expType3
btn3.Layout.Row = 5;
btn3.Layout.Column = 2;
% button expType4
btn4.Layout.Row = 6;
btn4.Layout.Column = 2;
% button undefined
btn5.Layout.Row = 7;
btn5.Layout.Column = 2;
% x plot
axX.Layout.Row = [2 4];
axX.Layout.Column = 1;
% y plot
axY.Layout.Row = [5 7];
axY.Layout.Column = 1;

% configure modules
axX.Title.String = 'Current Experiment Cursor x-data';
axY.Title.String = 'Current Experiment Cursor y-data';

% plot data on axes
plot(axX, xCur)
plot(axY, yCur)

% callback functions for buttons

    function btn_callback(src,event,newValue)
        
        myhandles = guidata(gcbo);
        myhandles.expType = newValue;
        guidata(gcbo,myhandles)
        
        closereq();
    end
    
    function btn_callback_2(src,event,newValue)
        
        myhandles = guidata(gcbo);
        myhandles.newType = newValue;
        fprintf('Experiment series value is %d\n',newValue);
        guidata(gcbo,myhandles) 
        
%         closereq();
    end


    function btn_callback_3(src,event,newValue)
        
        myhandles = guidata(gcbo);
        oldValue = myhandles.newType;
        fprintf('Test Experiment series value is %d\n',oldValue);
        guidata(gcbo,myhandles)
        
        
        closereq();
    end

end
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, it has given me more understanding of how handles work in MATLAB. However, either I still don't fully understand or this hasn't solved the issue. My problem isn't getting the GUI parent to read the variable, it's for the script that opens the GUI to read the variable. When running the following script using your functions I am getting an error that the fig.expType is "Unrecognized method, property, or field 'expType' for class 'matlab.ui.Figure'."
 SCRIPT (shortened): 
[fig,currentExpType] = guiExpType(xCur,yCur);
waitfor(fig);
temp = guihandles(fig.expType);

Comment: guihandles is part of the GUI. So you cannot use the guihandles outside the GUI. If you like the script to read the variable, export the variable . If you have mutliple variables that you would like to export, you can group them as a a cell and export that. Let me add some code to my earlier code to give you an idea.

Comment: It seems that the GUI closes before the output is exported. The variable 'currentExpType' is still empty after the gui is closed. Maybe it's because the gui is closed within the btn_callback function, then no further lines of the guiExpType function are executed? I have this thread and it might be more what I'm looking for, but it seems a bit overly complicated for the seemingly simple issue I have (https://nl.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/480328-return-data-from-guide-on-figure-close).

Comment: Inside the function, 'guiExpType', if you were to comment this line "dataType = myhandles.expType;" & instead add this test line "dataType = 22;" .  The output says >> Experiment series 1 is type 22 (user input) . Therefore the output is exported although the GUI closes.

Comment: Yes, that indeed works, I have tried that and understand that, but that works based on me knowing the data type as soon as I create the GUI. The Data type should be assigned by the buttons via the 'newValue' variable. The buttons should be able to change the dataType (i.e. button 2 with callback '@(src,event)btn_callback(src,event,2)' should change dataType to '2'). The 'dataType = myhandles.expType;' line currently saves the initial value (used to initiate the variable) as the dataType and remains unchanged by the button presses.

Comment: I've changed the code again. Now dataType will change based on Button 2 press. In fact Button 3 will also be able to access this data using handles. Is this a better option?

Comment: It does work in the sense that it prints what I want. But I don't necessarily want to print the experiment type, the numeric experiment type is a placeholder value so that I know what data processing I need to do for each different data set. The gui I need simply allows the user to manually determine the experiment type when the preceding code is unable to identify (step response in positive or negative x or y direction). After that the rest of the script will perform some necessary data filtering and system identification on the signals.

Comment: The bulk of my code is what follows this GUI but it is enormously frustrating that I can't even make a simple GUI to aid the process even though by now I might aswell have manually looked through the ~900000 datapoints for ~50 sets. 

Don't mistake my frustration for ungratefulness, I enormously appreciate the time you have taken/are taking to help me!

Comment: ha. I understand your frustration. i learnt a lot from this GUI on how to base my GUI on a single or a large data set and then manipulate the data as i please. Hope this helps. 
https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/78092-gui-for-wav-file-visualization-and-analysis?s_tid=prof_contriblnk